# iOS: Regenerating UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uibutton

I'm making a very simple app. I have an UIButton and an UIImageView, and every time the button is pressed the image moves x: -44 and y: -41. What I'm trying to do is that when the image reaches a certain (x,y) point in the screen to regenerate at other point of the screen. I hope that makes sense.

Here is my code:

file. h

```
{

IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageOne;

}

-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender;
```

file. m

```
-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender{


//ImageOne moving down the screen

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f
                 animations:^{

                     ImageOne.center = CGPointMake(ImageOne.center.x -44, ImageOne.center.y +41);

                 }];
```

How can I do this using if statements?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends. If you want to simply monitor the position before the move is done, then you can do the following:

```
-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender{
CGPoint newCenter = ImageOne.center;

// check the image's position
if (ImageOne.center.x < some_x) {
    newCenter.x = some_other_x;
} else if (ImageOne.center.y > some_y) {
    newCenter.y = some_other_y;
} else {
    newCenter =  CGPointMake(ImageOne.center.x -44, ImageOne.center.y +41);
    //ImageOne moving down the screen

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f
                     animations:^{
                         ImageOne.center = newCenter;
                     }];
}
```

Or if you want to catch that during the movement and modify the position, you should try the [Key-Value Observing](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/) to see when the `.center` changes.

I'm not sure if this regular `UIView`'s animation would work with `KVO`, maybe you'll need to implement the animation using [Facebook's `Pop` animation library](https://github.com/facebook/pop).